# Executing JS in Java JVM with dom context

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, dom

I'm currently working on my little project and I've encountered a small(or big) difficulty.

I'm writing a Java program that goes on a website extract and runs some JavaScript code. I'm using ScriptEngineManager to run JavaSript code in **JVM** but some code like `document.getInnerHtml().getElementById()` doesn't work because of no access to dom context.

Is any way I can run it?

Comment: Please try to provide a [mre] to help us understanding your problem

Answer (score 0):

So, here is an example

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
  
      var a = document.getElementById('k');
     
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" id="k">+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]))</div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

So, my java program will try to run that "document.getElementById('k')" code, but he won't see where is that HTML div so will throw a document is not defined.

So, in Java is ScriptEngineManager that can let you eval Javascript code but it won't have access to html document so it won't work for code like this one.